# Joining two tables conditioned by third in NHibernate mapping file

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have following tables:

```
foo {
    id;
    catColorId;
}

bar {
    fooId;
    catTypeId;
    barName;
}

cat {
     catColorId;
     catTypeId;
     priority;
}
```

`bar` table has composite-id `fooId, catTypeId`
`cat` table has composite-id `catColorId, catTypeId`

I would like to map those to:

```
class Foo {
    int Id;
    IList<Bar> BarList { get; set; }
}
```

`BarList` should be ordered by cat.priority

Any ideas how to map this in .hbm.xml?

**Update:**

It would be perfect if I could get mapping that, when filling in Foo.BarList, would generate query (or some variation of it):

```
select 
    b.fooId, 
    b.catTypeId,
    b.barName,
from
    join foo as f 
    join bar as b on f.id = b.fooId
    join cat as c on f.catColorId = c.catColorId and b.catTypeId = c.catTypeId
where
    f.id = @fooId
order by 
    c.priority
```

I have difficulty with that last join: `b.catTypeId = c.catTypeId`
How do you define such restriction in hbm markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example as it stands is strictly a `Many-To-Many` mapping.

```
public class Foo {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
}

// there is no Bar entity in this example; it is a cross-reference table used by nhibernate, but there is no entity in your domain

public class Cat {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    assembly="Models"
    namespace="Models">
    <class name="Foo" table="foo">
        <id name="Id" column="Id">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <bag name="Cats" table="bar">
            <key column="FooId"></key>
            <many-to-many column="CatId" class="Cat" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    assembly="Models"
    namespace="Models">
    <class name="Cat" table="cat">
        <id name="Id" column="Id">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <bag name="Foo" table="bar">
            <key column="CatId"></key>
            <many-to-many column="FooId" class="Foos" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

However, if the relationship between Foos and Cats is more meaningful than just the relationship (like, you need to add additional attributes to Bar), you'd do something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public virtual Cat Cat { get; set; }
}

public class Cat {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
// you can get all Cats for a Foo via Foo.Bars and vice versa
```

Mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    assembly="Models"
    namespace="Models">
    <class name="Foo" table="foo">
        <id name="Id" column="Id">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <bag name="Bars" inverse="true">
            <key column="CatId"></key>
            <one-to-many class="Bar"/>
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    assembly="Models"
    namespace="Models">
    <class name="Cat" table="cat">
        <id name="Id" column="Id">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <bag name="Bars" inverse="true">
            <key column="FooId"></key>
            <one-to-many class="Bar"/>
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    assembly="Models"
    namespace="Models">
    <class name="Bar" table="bar">
        <composite-id>
          <key-many-to-one class="Foo" name="Foo" column="FooId" />
          <key-many-to-one class="Cat" name="Cat" column="CatId" />
        </composite-id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Sorry if my HBM markup is rusty; I am used to mapping by code.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this is not quite right. As i understand many-to-many relationship takes into account two references A -> AC -> C. I need to mind A -> C reference too. :(

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your example indicates that A <-> C through a cross-reference, or A <- B -> C. Either still allows you to access All the A's that belong to C and vise versa. The difference with the second relationship is that B is not merely a cross-reference, but an entity or value object that binds A and C with the addition of other meaningful values.

Comment: Updated my question with sql query example that I would like to get as end result.

Comment: I guess you could say every table could be used as cross reference for other two in this example. It is sort of triangle of tables and if you filter results only on to references without third you will get some additional results along with correct ones.

Comment: Reflecting back to this question I see that my approach to problem was  incorrect. So I am marking this question as correctly answered.